# UITableView reloadData - how to stop flicker

Tags: uitableview

I have a problem with UITableView flicker.

I have a *hidden* UITableView that I want to refresh before it's shown to the user. Doing so causes the tableview to be displayed above all the other subview very briefly before it's hidden again.

Even code like this isn't helping:

```
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.tableView.hidden = YES;
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Tim

Answer (score -3):

I've solved this.

I need to remove the table view from the view hierarchy, reload the data, then put it back!

Comment: what's the statement u write to remove tableview from the view hierarchy? can you please post the code?

Comment: I just tried what you said, it didn't work. can you please post the code especially the part how you take the view off and put it back? thanks!