# Swift: How to use "estimatedRowHeight" ?Dynamic Cell Height Stange errors

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `TableViewController`, which contains 2 `ImageView`, some `UILabel`.I set up the contains like this: 
[image]

everything seems fine. and for the last `UILabel`, I want to show all the content based on the length of the content, which means I need the `TableViewCell` to adjust its height dynamically. I used this code to achieve this function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

It works. However, when I scroll the `TableView`, somethings strange happen, the screen flashed, and you can not scroll back to the top, something like this:
[image]

sorry I don't know how to show this error properly, it's flashing, and you cannot scroll the screen, you can only choose the `back` button.

I guess this maybe something wrong with the `AutoLayout` constrains, or the `estimatedRowHeight`, here I just set it to `70` based on the tutorial I learnt, I don't know how to set this value properly.

Comment: Problem solved, I checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437610/reloading-table-causes-flickering), and I have the same issue, since every time I scroll the table view, it downloads images, thats why it flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your UI's setup looks alright. There should be another problem regarding `datasource` i think. In your both imageview and your labels, how you setting respective value is also affect. For example if you getting data from server then you should cache the images for reuse because tableview `deque` the cells.

If you are getting images from server then you should cache the images. to do that you can use great library [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) .

So check twice that what causes problem. According to me constraints and UI's setup is fine!

Comment: Thanks for checking my problem, yes, something went wrong when I download data from the Internet, I fixed it, and now it works fine. Thanks anyway