# why tableview cells are starts flickering when they are going to be reused?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm building a chat interface. I'm using multiple types of tableView cells in `UITableView`. Table view cells are start flickering when new cell is added into `tableView` from reusablecell. I'm dequeuing tableview cells with following piece of code. How get scrolling smooth with out any flickering.

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageLessonTableViewCell") as! MessageLessonTableViewCell
```

Comment: are you reloading tableView in your app ?

Comment: @PranavGupte i'm adding new tableview cells in two methods. self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: animation)
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)

Comment: and adding element datasource and using tableview.reloaddata()

Comment: Both methods didn't help me much

Comment: because use of  tableView.reloaddata() several times cause flikering effect see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196927/reload-uitableview-with-new-data-caused-flickering

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for flickering is that, tableView is getting data to be attached late in time. So when you scroll, it takes time to switch from one type of tableViewCell to another. Plus you might be doing DB operations in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which delays in returning tbaleViewCell. For implementing Smooth scrolling refer [this](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.hohtkn97y)

Comment: I tried to do cell cofiguration in willdisplay cell. still it didn't work.

Comment: If you are doing in DB operations either in willDisplay or cellForRowATIndexPath, try to get that all data in a array and while use it in displaying on cell  content. Don't perform DB operations for per cell.

Comment: Problem is happening only when i tried to add new cell. at that time only scrolling is flickering. suppose user want to add message then it is flickering.

Comment: Use beginUpdate and endUpdate when you insert new cell.

Comment: Using that still it didn't help. I think problem is happening because all cells are dynamic height and reusing cells

Comment: If you are using dynamicHeight then your constraints must be proper. When you use dynamic height it takes some time to calculate height of cell at run time. You can use some basic animation as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @vishal Sonawane i'll try that.

Comment: Instead of calculating manually can i use this UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: That's what I told you. Using dynamicHeight is nothing but  UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Only thing which you will need to take care of is that make sure your constraints are proper.

Comment: @chandramohan You can mark my answer as correct if it has helped you.

Comment: @chandramohan Did you finally solved your problem? because I have the same error :(