# [self.tableview reloadData]; causes flickering

Tags: ios, tableview, reloaddata

The problem is the UI appears and then gets updated : giving a flickering affect.

I want the UI to be updated only once when user enters app, thus i've put reload in ViewDidLoad.. Here is the code .. Any help how can remove this flickering ... Some code example would help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

[super viewDidLoad];

self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
self.myTableView.delegate = self;

PFQuery * getCollectionInfo = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Collection"];   // make query

[getCollectionInfo orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
[getCollectionInfo setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    [getCollectionInfo findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            CollectionQueryResult = (NSMutableArray *)objects;
                [self.tableView reloadData];


            // whenevr get result
        }
        else{
            //no errors
        }


    }];
});
```

Comment: what is your issue, please elaborate your question.

Comment: The problem is the UI appears and then gets updated : giving a flickering affect.

Comment: I require the cells to be updated without the full TableView flickering .. I refered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631104/uitableview-reloaddata-how-to-stop-flicker but didnt help

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply call reloadSections method instead of [self.tableView reloadData];

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: still the image on tableview is flickering.

Answer (score 2):

Refer `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. You might be doing some operation that might cause a flick. In my case, I was setting an image of an image view with animation. So whenever I reload the table, it was flickering due to that animation.

I removed that animation and worked for me..

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below lines can help you in delaying and flickering issues

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
                   , ^{
 [self.tableView reloadData];

 });
```

Comment: actually tableview only reload visible cells by default

Comment: **I understand i need to do this.**                    '[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];'
     **But that gives an error :**  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

Comment: This would stop a background thread related crash, but not a refresh flicker

Answer (score 1):

Your download is asynchronous, so it won't complete before the view is shown. So, whatever you have in `CollectionQueryResult` will get displayed.

You could either:

1. Clear `CollectionQueryResult` so the table isn't populated till you get an update
2. Compare `CollectionQueryResult` and `objects`, then update only the visible cells where the data has changed (before setting `CollectionQueryResult`)

Note that for option 2 you will also need to compare the count of `CollectionQueryResult` and `objects` and then insert / delete rows from the table view as appropriate. The whole point of option 2 is to not call `reloadData`, so you need to do a lot more work...

You can also avoid calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` if you get the visible cells and update them directly (which avoids any animation from happening). See [`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_29).

Comment: **I understand i need to do this.**                    `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`
     **But that gives an error :**  'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

Comment: How can deal with this error , coz i am not passing the no. of rows manually

Comment: The number of rows is returned in the delegate method. If you update `CollectionQueryResult` then you need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` based on the difference between the old and new contents of `CollectionQueryResult`