# I am loading image in table view cell asynchronously It's working perfectly fine but when i scroll down the image is flickering

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

I am loading image in table view cell  asynchronously  It's working perfectly fine but when i scroll down the image is flickering...

## import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

[cell.imgProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrSearchedPic objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
NSLog(@"download completed...");
}];

user this code as well  still image flicker is there anything which i am missing please let me know

any help will be appreciable.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[self.tableview reloadData\]; causes flickering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312197/self-tableview-reloaddata-causes-flickering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SDWebImage for load asynchronously image
Use this link

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage download the library ..add files in the folder add all the files from SDWebImage folder into your project and import this file #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
the add this to you cellforRow at index path method
 [cell.imgProfileImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[profileImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

cell.imgprofileImage will be you imageview in which you want to load the data..